# Можно ли закрыть модальное окно при нажатии на крестик в input search?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, input

В моем проекте есть `<input type="search">` в который я ввожу информацию. Когда я ввожу запрос в поле поиска появляется модальное окно с вариантами поиска, оно пропадает только в том случае, если я удалю весь текст в `input` при помощи backspace.

У `<input type="search">` при написании текста появляется стандартный крестик который стирает текст. И если на него кликнуть, то текст в `input` пропадает конечно, а вот модальное окно остается и помогает только backspace и перезагрузка страницы.

Вот тут вопрос. Можно ли закрывать модальное окно, когда я буду нажимать на стандартный крестик в `<input type="search">`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function lightbg_clr() {
  $('#qu').val("");
  $('#livesearch').css({
    "display": "none"
  });
  $("#qu").focus();
};

function fx(str) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById("qu").value;
  var xmlhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display = "block";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "call_ajax.php?n=" + s1, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="search" />
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, но вы даже не упомянули, а что за модальное окно и как оно открывается? Это какой либо плагин? И привели код, который ни коем образом не относится к проблеме вопроса. Как вариант. Слушать событие `oninput` и проверять значение. Если `value` пустое - закрывайте модальное окно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обрабатывать событие нажатия на крестик используйте атрибут событий [onsearch](http://basicweb.ru/html/event_onsearch.php). Правда у него есть одна особенность, он срабатывает и при нажатии `Enter`.

```js
function onSearch() {
  alert('ты нажал на крестик');
}
```

```html
Введи текст и нажми на крестик.
<input type="search" onsearch="onSearch()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function($){
 var livesearch = $("#livesearch"),
  qu = $('#qu'),
  fx = function(e) {
   var s1 = $.trim(qu.val()),
    xmlhttp;
   if (s1.length == 0) {
    livesearch.html("").hide();
    return;
   }
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     livesearch.html(xmlhttp.responseText).show();
    }else{
          livesearch.html('error').show();
        }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "call_ajax.php?n=" + s1, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  };
 qu.on('input', fx).trigger('input');
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="qu" type="search">
<div id="livesearch" style="background:#ccc;min-height: 100px;"></div>
```